# Events with string argument not working (not indexed)

Tags: solidity, events, string

I am trying to listen to an event on rinkeby test which I run locally. Every thing works fine when my argument is int such as  `event EventTester(int values);` When I change the event argument to string (it is not indexed) it does not work and I do not see the log. `event EventTester(string values);` . Any idea why? I do not see the Events Log tab when I check the transaction on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io.

Thanks

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Web3 = require('web3');
var util = require('ethereumjs-util');
var tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var lightwallet = require('eth-lightwallet');
var txutils = lightwallet.txutils;
var web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')
);
var address = '0x.....';
var key = '';
var bytecode = '6060...90029';
var interface = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"input","type":"string"}],"name":"getOut","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"values","type":"string"}],"name":"EventTester","type":"event"}]

function sendRaw(rawTx) {
    var privateKey = new Buffer(key, 'hex');
    var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
    transaction.sign(privateKey);
    var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(
    '0x' + serializedTx, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("ERROR HAPPENED:" +err);
        } 
    });
}

var contractAddress = '0x...';

strInterface='[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"input","type":"string"}],"name":"getOut","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"values","type":"string"}],"name":"EventTester","type":"event"}]'
abiDefinition = JSON.parse(strInterface)
myContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition)
var contractInstance = myContract.at(contractAddress)

var txOptions = {
    nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
    gasLimit: web3.toHex(700000),
    gasPrice: web3.toHex(10000000000),
    to: contractAddress
};
var rawTx = txutils.functionTx(interface, 'getOut', ["hi"], txOptions);
sendRaw(rawTx);
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: The code is very straightforward

`pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract SimpleContract {
    event EventTester(string  values);
    mapping(address => uint) callers;
    function SimpleContract() public{}
    
    function getOut(string input) public {
        EventTester(input);
        callers[msg.sender] +=1;
    }
}`
The listener is 

`event.watch(function(error, result){
    if (!error){
        console.log(result);
    }else {
        console.log('Error happened')
    }
});`

If you change string to int everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave it a try on Ropsten and seems to be working. Here's the transaction: https://gist.github.com/pabloruiz55/d73fabb23677f146c58d8c4d3950c0fa

You can see on the logs I sent a string "hola".

The code I used is exactly the same you wrote, tested it on Remix.

(Could not test it on Rinkeby as I just run out of Ether, but if you send me some, I'll gladly give it a try: 0x0fC20E774EA6674087494a36F8F8f09a4Ee3a131)

Update: Working fine on Rinkeby as well.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x5cf1cfd9c401b9b2d2c0d7a7d967f50e33aaa9bf9cfc97afad9f90b247a93ee9#eventlog

Here's a screen capture of Remix, just in case.
[image]

Comment: It is really strange that it worked there. I sent you the ether. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Works well on Rinkeby. Uploaded a screenshot of Remix above, just in case, so you can compare to what you are doing. @user5908755

Comment: if you do not mind, can you share the code that sends the transactions. I am using node to submit my transaction. I tried to the same contract you created and still does not work. Maybe my js code has an issue with strings (and not with int lol). I edited the original post to include my code

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a constraint to use web3, I suggest you to use it to call the method, that will avoid you lot of common errors (already resolved in the wrapper).

with web3@^0.20.6:

```
contractInstance.getOut.sendTransaction('hi', (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  console.log(result);
});
```

with web3@^1.0.0

```
contractInstance.methods.getOut('hi').send({ from: address }).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```